# Efficient function to calculate generations on large dataset

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of over 30,000 individuals and am trying to create a column which contains the number of generations into population "Z" each individual is. Here is the dummy data I'm using to write the code.

```
Finaldf <- data.frame(
  anonID = 1:20,
  birthType = c("W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z"),
  ParentAnonID = c(-1, 1, 1, 2, 4, -2, -2, 6, 6, 7, -3, -3, 11, 12, 13, -4, -4, 16, 16, 17),
```

This is the code I have to calculate the new variable:

```
# Create an empty column for "Gen" in the dataset
Finaldf$Gen <- 0

# Calculate generations
for (id in 1:nrow(Finaldf)) {
  current_id <- id
  generation <- 1
  
  while (!is.na(Finaldf$ParentAnonID[current_id]) && Finaldf$ParentAnonID[current_id] != -1) {
    parent_index <- which(Finaldf$anonID == Finaldf$ParentAnonID[current_id])
    if (length(parent_index) == 0) {
      break
    }
    current_id <- parent_index[1]
    generation <- generation + 1
  }
  
  Finaldf$Gen[id] <- generation
}
```

While this code runs perfectly on the dummy data, it has taken hours on the large dataset and is still ongoing. Is this to be expected with such a large dataset or is there a more efficient code I could run that would accomplish the same task?

Comment: Can you please explain the algorithm? Not too sure if I get it correctly from your code approach.

Comment: Your sample data is incomplete, are there more columns?

Comment: @r2evans  `combined <- data.frame(
  anonID = 1:20,
  Sex = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female"),
  birthType = c("W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z"),
  ParentAnonID = c(-1, 1, 1, 2, 4, -2, -2, 6, 6, 7, -3, -3, 11, 12, 13, -4, -4, 16, 16, 17),
  IOCSpecies = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D")
)`

Comment: @r2evans yes sorry, attaching sample dataset in full.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to ask for recursively finding parents until reaching an initial condition (or negative value).  A data.table solution that should be significantly faster:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  anonID = 1:20,
  birthType = c("W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z"),
  ParentAnonID = c(-1, 1, 1, 2, 4, -2, -2, 6, 6, 7, -3, -3, 11, 12, 13, -4, -4, 16, 16, 17)
)

dt[, gen := 1]
dt[, pid := ParentAnonID]

while(max(dt$pid) > 0){
  dt[pid %in% anonID,
     gen := gen + 1]
  # This part finds the parents, if any
  dt[, pid := fifelse(pid < 0, pid, ParentAnonID[pmax(pid, 1)])]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Could I get more information on what `dt[, pid := ParentAnonID]` does? I am receiving the following error message: `Error in while (max(dt$pid) > 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` and having trouble trouble-shooting.

Comment: `dt[, pid := ParentAnonID]` creates a copy of the ParentAnonID column, which is then subsequently modifed as parents are traced back to the first element.  With that error it looks like your final data set has missing values, in which case you will need `max(dt$pid, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this reductive method:

```r
tmp <- list(Finaldf$ParentAnonID[match(Finaldf$ParentAnonID, Finaldf$anonID)])
while (any(!is.na(tmp[[length(tmp)]] > 0) & tmp[[length(tmp)]] > 0)) {
  tmp <- c(tmp, list(Finaldf$ParentAnonID[match(tmp[[length(tmp)]], Finaldf$anonID)]))
}
Finaldf$Gen2 <- rowSums(!is.na(do.call(cbind, tmp))) + 1
Finaldf
#    anonID birthType ParentAnonID Gen Gen2
# 1       1         W           -1   1    1
# 2       2         Z            1   2    2
# 3       3         Z            1   2    2
# 4       4         Z            2   3    3
# 5       5         Z            4   4    4
# 6       6         W           -2   1    1
# 7       7         W           -2   1    1
# 8       8         Z            6   2    2
# 9       9         Z            6   2    2
# 10     10         Z            7   2    2
# 11     11         W           -3   1    1
# 12     12         W           -3   1    1
# 13     13         Z           11   2    2
# 14     14         Z           12   2    2
# 15     15         Z           13   3    3
# 16     16         W           -4   1    1
# 17     17         W           -4   1    1
# 18     18         Z           16   2    2
# 19     19         Z           16   2    2
# 20     20         Z           17   2    2
```

That's a bit of an eyesore to look at, I'll try to step through it.

- `match(ParentAnonID, anonID)` returns the row of the matching parent for each row passed, `NA` if no match.

  ```r
  match(Finaldf$ParentAnonID, Finaldf$anonID)
  #  [1] NA  1  1  2  4 NA NA  6  6  7 NA NA 11 12 13 NA NA 16 16 17
  ```
- `ParentAnonID[match(..)]` returns the parent's ID for each of the matches in the previous step, which is positive (if the parent exists and has a parent), negative (if the parent exists but has no parents), or `NA` (nothing found)

  ```r
  Finaldf$ParentAnonID[match(Finaldf$ParentAnonID, Finaldf$anonID)]
  #  [1] NA -1 -1  1  2 NA NA -2 -2 -2 NA NA -3 -3 11 NA NA -4 -4 -4
  ```
- the above is the starting condition, which finds the second-level, we need to iterate until we find no more parents ... if we take the return value of that and replace the inner reference to `ParentAnonID`, we can iterate until we find no more matches

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Finaldf)[
  ,iParentRow := match(ParentAnonID, anonID)
][
  ParentAnonID < 0, Gen := 1L
]

while(anyNA(Finaldf$Gen)) {
  Finaldf[is.na(Gen) == TRUE, Gen := Finaldf$Gen[iParentRow] + 1L]
}

Finaldf[,iParentRow := NULL][]
#>     anonID    Sex birthType ParentAnonID IOCSpecies Gen
#>  1:      1 Female         W           -1          A   1
#>  2:      2 Female         Z            1          A   2
#>  3:      3   Male         Z            1          A   2
#>  4:      4 Female         Z            2          A   3
#>  5:      5   Male         Z            4          A   4
#>  6:      6 Female         W           -2          B   1
#>  7:      7 Female         W           -2          B   1
#>  8:      8 Female         Z            6          B   2
#>  9:      9   Male         Z            6          B   2
#> 10:     10   Male         Z            7          B   2
#> 11:     11 Female         W           -3          C   1
#> 12:     12 Female         W           -3          C   1
#> 13:     13 Female         Z           11          C   2
#> 14:     14   Male         Z           12          C   2
#> 15:     15 Female         Z           13          C   3
#> 16:     16 Female         W           -4          D   1
#> 17:     17   Male         W           -4          D   1
#> 18:     18   Male         Z           16          D   2
#> 19:     19 Female         Z           16          D   2
#> 20:     20 Female         Z           17          D   2
```

With `igraph`:

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  unique(
    rbind(
      data.frame(from = 0, to = Finaldf$ParentAnonID[Finaldf$ParentAnonID < 0]),
      data.frame(from = Finaldf$ParentAnonID, to = Finaldf$anonID)
    )
  )
)

d <- distances(g, V(g)[1], V(g))
Finaldf$Gen <- d[match(as.character(Finaldf$anonID), colnames(d))] - 1

Finaldf
#>    anonID    Sex birthType ParentAnonID IOCSpecies Gen
#> 1       1 Female         W           -1          A   1
#> 2       2 Female         Z            1          A   2
#> 3       3   Male         Z            1          A   2
#> 4       4 Female         Z            2          A   3
#> 5       5   Male         Z            4          A   4
#> 6       6 Female         W           -2          B   1
#> 7       7 Female         W           -2          B   1
#> 8       8 Female         Z            6          B   2
#> 9       9   Male         Z            6          B   2
#> 10     10   Male         Z            7          B   2
#> 11     11 Female         W           -3          C   1
#> 12     12 Female         W           -3          C   1
#> 13     13 Female         Z           11          C   2
#> 14     14   Male         Z           12          C   2
#> 15     15 Female         Z           13          C   3
#> 16     16 Female         W           -4          D   1
#> 17     17   Male         W           -4          D   1
#> 18     18   Male         Z           16          D   2
#> 19     19 Female         Z           16          D   2
#> 20     20 Female         Z           17          D   2
```